# Smooth surface plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a smooth plot in Python. Generally, you can make a plot that looks like the one below:

[image]

[Source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)

While this is a nice image, it looks as though it's made out of a mesh of polygons, making it look "coarse." In my own plots I have tried increasing the resolution of my function to no avail. I am trying to achieve the following "smooth" look:

[image]

[Source](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/r-data-visualization/9781788398312/6e096fab-09b2-4800-acad-af3c6b47e454.xhtml)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: Apologies, the code I'm using is in the source of the first example image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you were missing `rcount` and `ccount`?

```py
# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.05)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, rcount=200, ccount=200)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

[image: Sombrero]